# Using knex to read from a mysql database. How do i get information out of it?

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

I'm using a MySQL database with Node.js as the server-side and am using Knex.js to put data into the database. I can do that successfully, but how do I actually pull data out of it? All I want to do is console.log an entire table so I know I can access the data. From there I should be able to figure out how to implement it into my React project.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Thre are quite a few tutorials for knex.js out there to get you started. Here on SO we don't do tutorials, so your question is not a good fit. Provide your existing attempt at querying your database and describe what went wrong with it and we will help you in fixing your code.

Comment: http://knexjs.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much smallest example:

```
let knex = require('knex')({ 
  client: 'mysql', 
  connection: '<mysql connection string>' 
});
knex('tableName')
  .where('colName', 'something')
  .then(res => console.log(res));
```

Comment: Thank you, this was a helpful response.